# How do you remove the “The Link You Followed Has Expired” error for a subfolder website?

Tags: themes, htaccess, server, php.ini

I am building a wordpress website in a subfolder of a drupal website.
I want to add a new theme by uploading a theme file but I keep getting the “The Link You Followed Has Expired” error. From my understanding, this error is a configuration issue. I need to increase the maximum upload file size. However, no matter what I try, it does not work. Here is what I have tried so far :

1/ Add the following lines to the .htaccess of the subfolder website :

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 128M
php_value post_max_size 128M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300
```

Unfortunately, when I do this, I cannot reach the subfolder website anymore. I always end up on the root website's welcome page instead.

2/ Create a php.ini in the subfolder with the following lines :

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
max_execution_time = 300
```

That did not change anything. I still have the limitation and the error (sorry it is in French) :

[image: Limitation]

[image: Error]

I called phpinfo in the subfolder and the upload limit seems to be set properly so that is a little weird. This is what I get with the php.ini file in the subfolder.

[image]

If possible, I would really like to avoid modifying anything in the root website.
Could you please help me?

Comment: Can you upload the theme via FTP and then just activate it from the theme panel?  Also, how big is your theme ZIP archive?  If it's less than 64mb you shouldn't be seeing this.

Comment: Yes that is what I ended up doing. But I don't know why the php.ini method did not work... The zip was about 7MB.

Comment: It may be something down to the host and whether or not they're interfering with/controlling permissions and sizes etc.  I've found that adjusting either the PHP.ini or the USER.ini doesn't always have an effect if the hosting has rules written to override that.